# 5.15.0-52-generic kernel,syslog show a lot of "read not supported for file"

Tags: kernel, log

5.15.0-52-generic kernel,syslog show a lot of "read not supported for file"

```
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.284630] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:global_status_interface.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.284737] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:BUILD fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.284957] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:global_status.cpp fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285083] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:BUILD fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285192] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:nop_mode_manager_activity.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285288] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:parameters_manager fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285404] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:BUILD fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285527] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:parameters_manager.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285653] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:parameters_manager.cpp fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285751] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:pub_sub_inputs.json fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285855] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:nop_mode_manager_main.cpp fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.285920] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:functions_activity fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286019] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:functions_activity.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286089] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:BUILD fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286176] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:pub_sub_inputs.json fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286269] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:functions_activity.cpp fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286362] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:hmi_controller_activity fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286447] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:src fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286566] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:hmi_controller_activity.cpp fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286643] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:BUILD fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286721] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:include fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286838] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:vehicle_model_signal.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.286951] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:hmi_controller_activity.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.287040] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:utils.h fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.287148] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:hmi_controller_activity.launch fp is null,errno:1
Mar 20 10:16:30 ysj kernel: [  693.287242] dg_ff: dfc0630 open file:pub_sub_inputs.json fp is null,errno:1
```

Comment: Do you have a question, your question text appears to be only paste (*and details in the title may not be viewable on all devices when reading your question text, so details in title also need to be in your question text*)

Comment: You've also not told us your OS/release; only mentioning a kernel which is used by multiple OSes/releases